# Build Essentials

Tags: apt, compiling, c++, irc

Good morning everyone, the long and short of it is I'm setting up an interdomain IRC server for my company. To do so I needed a c++ compiler so I was directed to build essentials. However whenever I try to compile the  anope-2.0.2-source ./Config file I get the following

```
The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
Cmake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call stack CmakeLists.txt:19
```

Now I believe I have installed the apt correctly using:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
```

I then ran

```
gcc -v
make -v
```

I even inputted this since I saw it on a forum and figured it couldn't hurt

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin/c++/usr/bin/make
```

So am I missing a step in build essentials setup? Or am I missing a C++ compiler all together?

Comment: The package name is `build-essential` (singular, not plural): if installed **correctly** it should have included both `gcc` and `g++` as dependencies. There should be no need to mess with `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding your PATH variable, I believe, there are some typos

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin/c++/usr/bin/make
```

between `.../c++` and `/usr/bin...`

Use

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin/c++:/usr/bin/make
```

And install `g++`

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; it worked like a charm. I should also state that I noticed another typo after you pointed the first one out. after /sbin:/ it should be USR not URS.

Comment: I don't understand how this path (corrected or not) can work: `/usr/bin/c++` should be a symlink ultimately to `/usr/bin/g++-4.x` rather than a directory that needs to be added to the standard search path. Likewise `/usr/bin/make` should be an executable not a searchable directory. If `g++` is installed from the standard repository there should be no need to mess with `$PATH`.